# Can I recover data from RAID 1 drive after Windows installation?

Tags: windows, raid, data-recovery, raid-1

I had a  RAID 1 setup on Asus motherboard on windows XP. At some point one drive failed and I took it out. For a long time I continued to use the remaining drive without replacing the bad drive and ignoring the critical RAID error message.

Then a few days ago I disconnected  the remaining good RAID drive (which was my `D:` drive) and installed Windows 7 on my `C:` (non-raid). Then I plugged my raid drive back in but Windows does not see it.

How can I recover the data from this drive?

If I cancel/disable the RAID configuration in the BIOS would I lose the data? Or would the drive become a regular non-RAID drive? (wishful thinking).

Would I be able to read it if I plugged it into another PC?

Answer (score 2):

This question cannot be answered precisely without knowing what you are actually using for the RAID - whether it is motherboard RAID (which chipset?) or software RAID (Windows/hacked) or a standalone RAID card (what make/model?)

However, *in general* disabling the RAID on a motherboard will cause all drives to show up as normal standalone drives to Windows. *Most* RAID-1 setups when converted in this way will just appear as a normal drive. *Some* use proprietary metadata that may or may not offset the start of the true partition table causing Windows to fail to recognize it if taken out of RAID.

Comment: It's an Asus motherboard RAID. Does Asus place this metadata in the front of the drive?

Comment: I disabled the raid in the bios and rebooted. Started disk management. The drive showed as 'foreign'. Selected it and applied 'import foreign' and after that it showed in windows 7 and all the data seems to be fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sounds like you were using a dynamic disk in addition to motherboard RAID. Not that it makes any difference at this point.